# jQuery - Error: 'style' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I put jQuery on my page I get an error `Error: 'style' is null or not an object`

All i did was add the following to the `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
```

Comment: So you have no other JavaScript code?

Comment: post your javascript code, there must an error there

Comment: Also include the browser you are testing with, always useful with JS errors.

Comment: @Tom not the whole page im afraid, it's too large and confidential

Comment: @Dave819 - Post the !doctype you are using

Comment: @artyom.stv just this? or the whole declaration? im not using any other jquery version.  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: Well then how about the list of other JavaScript files you **are** using?

Comment: @pointy PacsExternalViewer.js DWRHttpUtils.js NavigationManager.js DatasetUtils.js util.js engine.js (dwr)  template.js

Comment: OK, well as noted in @Michael's answer, what's probably happening is that one of those scripts is perverting something on the page. Move your new jQuery `<script>` line to the *top* of the `<head>` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Dave819: Then remove the irrelevant and confidential bits.

Comment: @pointy that fixed it. i put the jquery before any other script. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a conflict with a second version of jQuery or some other library.